# IE6/7 - CSS popup within a - tr td

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

I am struggling with a CSS popup and hoping someone can help.

We have various tds that have this popup within their cell, in firefox, chrome etc (the usual) it works fine. However in the older browsers below IE8 it is having problems.

It seems that the :hover is lost when the mouse moves out of the cell, even if it moves over the popup area (which is situated just below the cell). You are probably saying yes that is what it should be doing but a child element of the parent that is hovered in firefox keeps the :hover class on the parent.

The popup div is positioned absolute and given a margin-left of -999px; (This is ok)

On :hover of the parent div element the margin-left is set to -125px (half of width of popup div, so it is centered - also ok)

All this is fine and works perfect in modern browsers as previously stated.

HTML Snippet

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="events">CONTENT</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="events">CONTENT</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="events">CONTENT</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="events">CONTENT</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="events">CONTENT</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS Thusfar

```
#page-content .block_calendar_month { overflow: visible; }

.tooltip { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000; outline: none; cursor: help; text-decoration: none; }

.tooltip span { margin-left: -999em; position: absolute; }
td.day:hover { background-color: #fbf16b; }

.tooltip:hover span { font-size: 12px; position: absolute; left: 0em; z-index: 5000; top: 1em; margin-left: -125px; width: 250px; }

.tooltip:hover span div { }
.events {padding: 0.8em 1em; }
```

Hope someone can give me some advice, as I have lost a few hours trying to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't touched IE6 in a while, but from working with IE7 I can tell you it does some funky stuff with tables and z-index. I found that the best solution when working with tooltip is to not use tables. Why not strip out the table code and have:

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <span class="events">CONTENT</span>
</div>
```

Also, I am not sure what plugin you are using (in fact, it looks like you aren't using any), But if you use JQuery Tools tooltip plugin, you can set the popup's offset distance as a JSON parameter. Read more http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/dynamic.html.

If you are going to keep the current implementation, I'd recommend toggling between display:block and display:none for the tooltip.

Comment: Yeah I'd love to change the markup as I knew IE7 was nasty with tables. It doesn't accept widths etc on tr and other such stuff where the modern browsers handle it no problem. Appreciate your response and may need to look at an alternative but was trying to work with the way it was, but once again IE has stood in the way. Also thanks for the link I will have a look but have been working in yui3 and have tried a few things such as making all the other tds and trs static except the one that is hovered but to no avail.

Comment: Ah, sorry I don't have more experience with YUI. I've played with the demos but that's about it. Best of luck to you.